# JavaScript custom event handler strategy advice

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I am in the middle of the design/development of a web store and am thinking my way through the best way of handling a transparent load of a couple of megabytes of product items. It seems the Asynchronous bit of AJAX doesn't mean parallel so I have to be a little bit creative here.

Rather than just pull a large lump of data down I was thinking of breaking it into pages of say 50->100 items and allowing the browser some time to process any internal messages.

The loader would pull down a page of data - fire a custom event to itself to get the next page.  Theory is that if the browser has other messages to process this event would queue up behind them allowing the browser do anything else it has to do. A loss of a bit of speed - but a smoother user experience.

Rinse and repeat.

Add in some smoke and mirrors engineering - a loading icon or some such - to keep the user from noticing any delays and I should be right.

Before I dive into what is starting to sound like a fun bit of code can anyone think of a better way to pull down a large lump of data in as smooth and friendly a way as possible? I am an ancient old programmer - but JavaScript is a bit new to me.

Am I reinventing the wheel - AJAX already does all this - and I just don't know about it?

Comment: Any specific JS frameworks in play?

Comment: seems [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) fits here

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to improve the situation:

a) reduce the data coming from the database - i.e. if there is some information, which is not used you don't need to load it. Also if there is non-changeable data you may cache it and request it only in the beginning once

b) load only the information which you need to show - that's the way which you thinking about, except the fact that you want to trigger new data loading automatically. Or at least that's what I understood. I'll suggest to keep the ajax requests as less as possible and make a new one only if the user needs more data. For example if the user stays on page 1 of 20, you don't need to fire loading of page 3 and 4. It's maybe good idea to load page 2, so the user could switch fast.